# Bitcoin transaction stuck since almost 3 weeks

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins

about 3 weeks before (06th December) I have send a bitcoin transaction from my Ledger Nano S to my Bitfinex account and until today (25th December) it still didn't get confirmed.
I have no clue why it takes so long as I am sure that I ticked the high fee.
The transaction is mentioned as an open deposit in my Bitfinex account already, but it had 0/3 confirms after 2 weeks, so I baught a paid accelerator service (https://pushtx.btc.com/) where I paid 80 USD and finally it started to get confirmed, but so far it has 416/3 confirms. How can I need so many confirms?

The TXID is: a3b9d2eef1305a845ebe4e1c0c5fe813f10dfbf7c6f39553a71ca829e885b5c0

I would highly appreciate if you guys could help me. Either it will be received on my Bitfinex account or back to my Ledger does not matter, I just want to have it somewhere since I am worried that I am loosing the BTC in the transaction.

Thank you guys in advance and I wish you a merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transaction has 428 confirmations. Some services are satisfied with one confirmation, while some require up to six. Anyway, with over 400 confirmations, it's clear that Bitfinex has received the deposit. If you haven't been credited for it yet, I suggest that you check that you have sent to the correct address, and then if that's the case you reach out to Bitfinex to have them remedy the missing deposit.